# Get Html Code, replace parts and store in variable as string without changing the DOM Element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a DOM Element

```
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="name"></div>
  <div class="id" data-id=""></div>
  <a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the HTML like `$('.list-item').html();`
Then i want to fill parts like data-attributes and content with own variables so i can get for example this:

```
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="name">NAME CONTENT</div>
  <div class="id" data-id="123456">CONTENT</div>
  <a href="https://link.de">Link</a>
</div>
```

Then i want to store that as string in a varibale like

```
var htmlCode = '<div class="list-item">.....';
```

The tricky part here is to do that **all in Javascript** without changing the DOM Element. I hope for help. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to modify the existing DOM element or create a new one.  You only seem to want to create a string that contains the existing DOM element's HTML code with the 'parts' filled in.  I would get the parent div's HTML using innerHTML or html(), as you show, then search the string for the places that you want to fill in and then put in the content that you want in the places using javascript's string functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. With your help i got this solution:

```
var $temp = $('.list-item').html();
var $code = temp.replace('data-id=""', 'data-id="1234"').replace('href=""', 'href="https://link.de"');
```

So $code is my varibale wich stores the html as string without changing the DOM Element :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.clone()` to clone your div and then use `.attr()` to change attr from `id` class .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var htmls = $(".list-item").clone()
$(htmls).find(".id").attr('data-id', 'somehting');
console.log($(htmls).html()) //store in variable..
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="name"></div>
  <div class="id" data-id=""></div>
  <a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<script>
    var html = $('.list-item').html();
    console.log(html);

    var list = $('<li></li>')

    $('.list-item').children().each(function(index,elem){  
        $(list).append($(elem).clone());
    })
    $(list).children().each(function(i,e) {
        $(e).data("id","1234")
        $(e).html("ll");
    })
    console.log($(list).children());
</script>
```